# MYSQL - Changing year of dates from 2020 to 2011

Tags: mysql, datetime, date, sql-update

I have bunch of dates in format YYYY-MM-DD

But I have all year in 2020-MM-DD

I want to change it to 2011-MM-DD

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What's the datatype of the column in question?

Comment: Data type of the column is date

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491906/changing-year-in-mysql-date) one is simpler solution

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET YourDateColumn = SUBDATE(YourDateColumn, INTERVAL 9 YEAR);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. I just tried it and it actually added 1 to year i.e. it made my date from 2020 to 2021. Is their any function to decrease the interval ?

Comment: Sorry I had mistyped my question. It is actually My dates are in format 2020-MM-DD and I want to convert it to 2010-MM-DD. I am so sorry

Comment: @ChinmayMurugkar To go from 2020 to 2011, use `SUBDATE(YourDateColumn, INTERVAL 9 YEAR)` I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 5):

USE `ADDDATE(old_date, INTERVAL -9 YEAR)`

Comment: Thanks for reply. Sorry I had mistyped my question. It is actually My dates are in format 2020-MM-DD and I want to convert it to 2010-MM-DD. I am so sorry

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect this.  The answer is slightly different than @Joe Stefanelli's, but works the same way.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE YourTable 
SET YourDateColumn = ADDDATE(YourDateColumn, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
WHERE YourDateColumn >= '2010-01-01'
AND YourDateColumn <= '2010-12-31';
```

If your table down not have an index on the date field, you could get away with this:

```
UPDATE YourTable 
SET YourDateColumn = ADDDATE(YourDateColumn, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
WHERE YEAR(YourDateColumn) = 2010;
```

To fix your date problem with 2020 going to 2021 run this:

```
UPDATE YourTable 
SET YourDateColumn = ADDDATE(YourDateColumn, INTERVAL -1 YEAR)
WHERE YEAR(YourDateColumn) = 2021;
```

BTW Since I copied Joe Stefanelli's original code, +1 for him !!!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add (for further visitors to the question) that you can also "update" positively faster than with `ADDDATE` statement with the `SUBDATE` function, I think is reasonably faster, while to `ADDDATE` took it aprox. 1 hour to affect 2.3 trillion rows `SUBDATE` made it half the time.

```
UPDATE Table SET DateTimeField = SUBDATE(DateTimeField, INTERVAL -x YEAR);
```

Where x is the negative number you want to add as new year value.
To be honest I ignore why this happens, but it works.