# Changing year in mysql date

Tags: mysql, date

I have a bunch of dates in our database stored in the standard mysql date type.

How can I covert a year to 2013, regardless of original date.

So if a date is 2009-01-01 it would be 2013-01-01, but if it's 2012-01-04, it'd convert to 2013-01-14.

I figured it'd be simple and obvious, but I couldn't figure it out =/

Comment: Did you mean `2013-01-04`?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

That's simple:

for DATETIME:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET date_col=DATE_FORMAT(date_col,'2013-%m-%d %T');
```

for DATE:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET date_col=DATE_FORMAT(date_col,'2013-%m-%d');
```

Answer (score 17):

The problem with the current answers is that none of them take leap year into account. If you take the date '2016-02-29' and convert it to the year 2013 through concatenation, you get '2013-02-29', which is not a valid date. If you run DATE_FORMAT('2013-02-29', '%Y-%m-%d') the result is `null`. See an example here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5358/11

A better way to change the year is to use DATE_ADD since it accounts for daylight savings. For example:

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(datecol, INTERVAL (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - YEAR(datecol)) YEAR), '%Y-%m-%d') `date`
FROM t;
```

You could substitute CURRENT_DATE() with '2013-01-01' if you still wanted to convert all dates to 2013 instead of the current year. An example of this solution is here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5358/12

Answer (score 11):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET    dateColumn = dateColumn + INTERVAL 4 YEAR
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd557/2)

other way is to concatenate it,

```
UPDATE Table1
SET    DateColumn = CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', DATE_FORMAT(dateColumn, '%m-%d'))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/801e8/1)

Answer (score 2):

If its a date field:

```
  UPDATE table_name SET date_field_name = CONCAT("2013", RIGHT(date_field_name,6));
```

If its a date time field:

```
UPDATE table_name SET date_field_name = CONCAT("2013", RIGHT(date_field_name,15));
```

Answer (score 2):

Current date from quest was 2013, I understand that you wish set current YEAR in date.

```
UPDATE table_name SET date_col=DATE_FORMAT('2013-05-06',YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-%m-%d);
```