# Set date to year in existing column

Tags: mysql

Hello there I am trying to update an existing column and set the year column from 1/1/2019 to just 2019. I am getting a syntax error not sure how to do this.  Thank You

```
UPDATE TABLE set year = YEAR(date_format(STR_TO_DATE(year,'%d/%m/%Y'))) 
WHERE id > 0;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491906/changing-year-in-mysql-date       Check this out

Answer (score 0):

I instead suggest that you *don't* store the year by itself, but rather create a new bona fide date column, and use `STR_TO_DATE` to populate it with your current data:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD COLUMN new_date DATETIME;
UPDATE yourTable
SET new_date = STR_TO_DATE(year, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

Afterwards, you may drop the previous text column `year`, assuming you don't need it anymore:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable DROP COLUMN year;
```

Note that if you want to obtain the year from `new_date`, then you may easily do so, e.g.

```
SELECT new_date, YEAR(new_date) AS year
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will Work For You Try this

```
UPDATE `Table` SET`Year`= STR_TO_DATE(year(CURDATE()),"%Y");
```

This will be only set the year but not the whole date

**----------------------Note-------------------------**

if you want to totally drop the month and the day change the datatype from date to year of your column in mysql if you want to know more about the Year datatype check out this link : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/year.html

Comment: @MuhammedAeraz  that converts the day and month to 00 but some of the years on my column are from prior years as far back as 2004 so I want the year to remain the same I just want to drop the month and day

Comment: You can change the datatype to year of the column in date and time section in mysql and then try the answer that i replied before hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out seems way more complicated than it should be.  You need to convert the date to unix_time and the from_unixtime you need to select the year

```
UPDATE my_table 
set year=YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(year, '%d/%m/%Y')))) 
WHERE id > 0;
```